# can't delete record table with sweet alert on codeiginter. but sweetalert's response is susceptible

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, sweetalert

In my application i use sweet alert to beautify deletion confirmation. the notification is successful but the data is not deleted.

**Please find the below code:**

**Javascript:**

```
  function delete_swal(id)
  {
    swal({
      title: "Delete?",
      text: "You won't be able to revert this!?",
      type: "warning",
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonColor: "#DD6855",
      confirmButtonText: "Yes, Hapus",
      closeOnConfirm: false
    },
    function(){
      $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/datastudents/deletestudent/?>",
        type: "POST",
        data: {id:id},
        success:function(){
          swal({type: 'success', title: 'Deleted', showConfirmButton: false, timer: 1500});
          $("#delete_ajax").fadeOut("slow", 0.7, function(){
            $(this).remove();
          });
        },
        error:function(){
          swal({type: 'error', title: 'Delete Error', showConfirmButton: false, timer: 1500});
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

**My Controller:**

```
function deletestudent($id)
{
    $where = array('id' => $id);
    $this->m_data->delete_data($where,'students');
    redirect('admin/datasiswa/
        ');
}
```

**My Model:**

```
function delete_data($where,$table)
    {
        $this->db->where($where);
        $this->db->delete($table);
    }
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: check if data is post or not echo $id; die();

Comment: Is the js function inside an html file or a js one? Btw try to use the network tab under developer tools of your browser to inspect the call made by Sweet alert and the eventual error returned by the controller/model.